# TreeMap filtered view performance

Tags: java, performance, treemap

I have a class that has (among other things):

```
public class TimeSeries {
  private final NavigableMap<LocalDate, Double> prices;

  public TimeSeries() { prices = new TreeMap<>(); }

  private TimeSeries(NavigableMap<LocalDate, Double> prices) {
    this.prices = prices;
  }

  public void add(LocalDate date, double price) { prices.put(date, price); }

  public Set<LocalDate> dates() { return prices.keySet(); }

  //the 2 methods below are examples of why I need a TreeMap

  public double lastPriceAt(LocalDate date) {
    Map.Entry<LocalDate, Double> price = prices.floorEntry(date);
    return price.getValue(); //after some null checks
  }

  public TimeSeries between(LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
    return new TimeSeries(this.prices.subMap(from, true, to, true));
  }
}
```

Now I need to have a "filtered" view on the map where only some of the dates are available. To that effect I have added the following method:

```
public TimeSeries onDates(Set<LocalDate> retainDates) {
  TimeSeries filtered = new TimeSeries(new TreeMap<> (this.prices));
  filtered.dates().retainAll(retainDates);
  return filtered;
}
```

The `onDates` method is a huge performance bottleneck, representing 85% of the processing time of the program. And since the program is running millions of simulations, that means hours spent in that method.

How could I improve the performance of that method?

Comment: How many times will the filtered `TimeSeries` copy be iterated over? Is `retainDates` typically a lot smaller than `prices`?

Comment: @biziclop the map typically contains 1500 entries and the set will be of almost the same size (possibly the same size, containing the same dates). The filtered TimeSeries is generally only used (iterated over) once.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with LocalDate, but would it be safe to simply do prices.get(localeDate) to get the value you want?

Comment: In that case the only thing I can say is that instead of creating a copy of the map, then calling `retainAll()`, start with an empty map and add the items that need to be kept. So you'll only iterate over the collection once and you'll save some memory too.

Comment: @coffeeaddict the dates have "holes" (for example the week ends or holidays are missing) - so if you call `lastPrice(someSaturday)` it needs to return the value for the previous day.

Comment: @assylias That's fine. I was more specifically talking about your onDates method. Create a new empty NavigableMap, then iterate through your set, and add any non-null value you get from calling prices.get(localeDate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd give [`ImmutableSortedMap`](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.html) a try, assuming you can use it. It's based on a sorted array rather then a balanced tree, so I guess its overhead is much smaller(*). For building it, you need to employ biziclop's idea as the builder supports no removals.

(*) There's a call to `Collection.sort` there, but it should be harmless as the collection is already sorted and `TimSort` is optimized for such a case.

---

In case your original map doesn't change after creating `onDates`, maybe a view could help. In case it does, you'd need some "persistent" map, which sounds rather complicated.

Maybe some hacky solution based on sorted arrays and binary search could be fastest, maybe you could even convert `LocalDate` first to `int` and then to `double` and put everything into a single interleaved `double[]` in order to save memory (and hopefully also time). You'd need your own binary search, but this is rather trivial.

---

The view idea is rather simple, assuming that

- you don't need all `NavigableMap` methods, but just a couple of methods
- the original map doesn't change
- only a few elements are missing in `retainDates`

An example method:

```
public double lastPriceAt(LocalDate date) {
    Map.Entry<LocalDate, Double> price = prices.floorEntry(date);
    while (!retainDates.contains(price.getKey()) {
        price = prices.lowerEntry(price.getKey()); // after some null checks
    }
    return price.getValue(); // after some null checks
}
```

Comment: That's an old version that was not navigable - the [latest one](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.html) is and I'll give it a try. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I have run a micro benchmark with 1500 data points and 3 missing dates in retainDates: my code takes 50 microseconds vs. 80 microseconds for your proposal. So you suggestion does improve biziclop's code significantly but is still slower that the original version. Thanks anyway!

Comment: After more tests it looks like the only way is to use a `LocalDate[] dates;` and `double[] prices;` and use a binarySearch  for `lastPriceAt`. using arrays improves performance by a factor of ~3x.

Comment: @assylias Do the dates represent days? Can you convert them easily to an `int`? Because in that case you can have a single array of prices, which could potentially be even faster, depending on how big the "gaps" are between days with prices specified.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest optimisation:

```
public TimeSeries onDates(Set<LocalDate> retainDates) {
  TreeMap<LocalDate, Double> filteredPrices = new TreeMap<>();
  for (Entry<LocalDate, Double> entry : prices.entrySet() ) {
      if (retainDates.contains( entry.getKey() ) ) {
          filteredPrices.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
      }
  }
  TimeSeries filtered = new TimeSeries( filteredPrices );
  return filtered;
}
```

Saves you the cost of creating a full copy of your map first, then iterating across the copy again to filter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it tomorrow. The copy constructor of TreeMap is optimised though so I don't know if this will be a faster. TBC then!

Comment: The constructor is optimised but `retainAll()` isn't: it just iterates blindly over the entire map. Although there is probably less tree rebalancing required when you're retaining. It's worth a try, I'm not saying it'll definitely work.

Comment: I have run a micro benchmark with 1500 data points and 3 missing dates in retainDates: my code takes 50 microseconds vs. 200 microseconds for your proposal. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think the hit is due in large part to resizing / rehashing.